# ATI Radeon 5670 Won't Show Resolutions over 1400x900

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, resolution

Just got my new Dell computer with Windows 7 and an ATI Radeon 5670.  I attached it to my current monitor, which is a Samsung 24" (2443bwt).  Windows 7 does not allow me to display in resolutions greater than 1400 x 900.

The setup through a VGA cable into the VGA port of the card.  The card also has a DVI port, but I need to use the VGA port because a KVM that supports VGA only.

My old PC (which is Windows XP, GeForce 8600 video) can display in 1900 x 1200 on the same monitor (which is what I want) and even higher.  It does this through a vga cable also connected to the KVM (through the DVI port but using an adapter).  I have tried the same setup (DVI => VGA adapter) on the new PC and nothing changed.

I have tried:

- Updating the drivers via Windows "Update Driver" (says they are current)
- Installing the updated version of the drivers from ATI (made no difference)
- Installing Powerstrip (all the options I would need for a custom resolution are greyed out)

Installing the drivers/software from ATI caused the ATI Catalyst Control Center software to stop functioning, so I can no longer even start it.  I have found some references to other people having this problem and instructions on cleaning the software off and reinstalling it (as uninstalling normally doesn't solve it).  I will try this tonight.  In any case, I didn't see any options in CCC that would allow me to override the settings for max resolution.  However I didn't tinker with it too much before I tried updating the drivers, so I may have missed a setting.

I contacted Samsung via online chat and they say it's a problem with the video card/driver (of course--what else would they say?).

Any thoughts on what else I could try?

Comment: Have you checked to see if the real maxm resolution is detected if the KVM is removed (so the monitor is directly connected to that machine)?

Comment: If this were the problem, would it not affect the XP PC as well (also connected through the KVM)?  In any case, I will try this tonight.  Would I reconnect and then reboot?  Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Hmm, made no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to finally resolve this last night.  They key is to get the Catalyst Control Center working fully with the Catalyst drivers.  My installation was broken (which seems to be common from googling), and once I got it all straightened out I was able to "force" a the correct resolution.